# Converting row entries to columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have my data in a dataframe in the following format:

```
ID  GRP   VAL
1    A    23
2    A    43
3    A    12
4    A    65
1    B    43
2    B    87
3    B    45
4    B    76
1    C    45
2    C    76
3    C    24
4    C    75
```

I want to convert to the following format:

```
ID   A    B    C
1    23   43   45
2    43   87   76
3    12   45   24
4    65   76   75
```

How can I get this done?

Is there a name for this kind of transformation?

Answer (score 5):

This is a very common "long" to "wide" transformation that is referred to as "reshaping" your data.

Here are a few options:

In base R:

```
> reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar="ID", timevar="GRP")
  ID VAL.A VAL.B VAL.C
1  1    23    43    45
2  2    43    87    76
3  3    12    45    24
4  4    65    76    75
> xtabs(VAL ~ ID + GRP, mydf)
   GRP
ID   A  B  C
  1 23 43 45
  2 43 87 76
  3 12 45 24
  4 65 76 75
```

You can also use `dcast` from the "reshape2" package (there's also `dcast.data.table` which is a rewrite of `dcast` but gives you a speed boost).

```
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(mydf, ID ~ GRP, value.var="VAL")
  ID  A  B  C
1  1 23 43 45
2  2 43 87 76
3  3 12 45 24
4  4 65 76 75
```

If you prefer chaining or piping commands together (it honestly hasn't grown on me yet), you can look into the "tidyr" package in conjunction with the "dplyr" package, with which you can do:

```
# devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  spread(GRP, VAL)
# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# 
#   ID  A  B  C
# 1  1 23 43 45
# 2  2 43 87 76
# 3  3 12 45 24
# 4  4 65 76 75
```

Comment: +1 for `xtabs` function, never came across this one before but good to know.